# Как поменять индекс массива в ассемблере?

Tags: ассемблер

Как в программе сделать, чтобы первое слагаемое ссылалось на `X[i-1]` вместо `X[i]` в формуле `Y[i]=A*X[i-1] + B*X[i]`?
Сейчас в программе просто `X[i]`

```
SDATA SEGMENT WORD PUBLIC 'DATA'
A   DB -5                               ;- это два коэффициента
B   DB 17
ARRAY_X     DB -1,22,-34,12,-51, 68     ; - массив чисел X
ARRAY_Y     DW 6  DUP(0)                ; - массив чисел Y
SDATA ENDS

SSTACK SEGMENT PARA STACK 'STACK'
DW 64 DUP (?)
STACK_POINT LABEL WORD
SSTACK ENDS

SCODE SEGMENT WORD PUBLIC 'CODE'
ASSUME CS:SCODE,DS:SDATA,SS:SSTACK

START:  
MOV AX,SDATA                            ; Запись сегментного адреса
MOV DS,AX                               ; Данных в регистр DS
MOV AX,SSTACK                           ; Определение сегмента стека
MOV SS,AX                               ; и указателя стека
MOV SP,OFFSET STACK_POINT
                                        ; Инициализация исходных данных
MOV SI,0                                ; SI содержит индекс массива X
MOV DI,0                                ; DI содержит индекс массива Y
MOV CX,6                                ; СX:= число элементов массива X

M1:
MOV AL, A                               ; AL:= коэффициент A
CBW                                     ; Расширение байта до слова
MOV BX, AX                              ; Сохранение коэффициента в BX                                  
MOV AL, ARRAY_X[SI]                     ; Занесение очередного элемента     массива X в аккумулятор
IMUL BX                                 ; AX:=A*X[I]
push AX                                 ; Помещение АХ в стек

MOV AL, B                               ; AL:= коэффициент B
CBW                                     ; Расширение байта до слова
MOV BX, AX                              ; Сохранение коэффициента в BX
MOV AL, ARRAY_X[SI]                     ; Занесение очередного элемента     массива X в аккумулятор
IMUL BX                                 ; AX:=B*X[I]
POP BX                                  ; Извлечение A*X[I] из стека
ADD AX,BX                               ; Y[I]=:A*X[I]+B*X[I]

MOV ARRAY_Y[DI], AX                     ; запись в массив Y
INC DI                                  ; увеличение DI на 1
INC DI                                  ; увеличение DI на 1
INC SI                                  ; увеличение SI на 1
LOOP M1                                 ; переход на метку M1

MOV AX,4C00H                            ; выход из программы
INT 21H                                 ; выполняется функция DOS, номер
SCODE   ENDS                            ; конец кодового сегмента программы
END START                               ; конец программы
```

Comment: а что делать в случае `i=0`, у вас ведь в массиве нет значения `x[-1]` =/ чему у вас должен быть равен `Y[0]`? `A*X[-1]+B*X[0]`?

Comment: @MrModest `i=0` это индекс первого элемента массива

Comment: это я знаю.. я к тому, что в самой же первой итерации цикла где вы возьмёте `X[i-1]`? У вас же индекс выйдет за пределы массива и захватит какой-то мусор, стоящий перед массивом =/